# PHP and Javascript - onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a link in my header.php from my website that has the following code:

```
<a onclick="irParaMinhasReservas();" style="cursor: pointer;" id="btnMinhasReservas2" class="ph00_9"></a>
```

Then, on my principal.js, I need to define a function that when I click on this link, it must go to the index.php page and automatically call a function named AbreAba. However, if I'm already on the index.php page, it will only need to call this function AbreAba.

How can I do this? I'm kinda lost on this programming and it seems so simple to do.

Comment: Is the method a JavaScript one or a php one?

Answer (score 0):

redirect on index.php on click with some argument like

in principal.js , it will be

```
irParaMinhasReservas(){

    //YOUR CODE and
    location.href = 'index.php?param=1';
}
```

Now, in index.php

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])){
   //call your function
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to write something after the word "like" and before "in principal.js". Did you?

Comment: But I didn't understand one thing: how do I define the variable 'param'?

Comment: It is just query string parameter which will be used to run specific code later ..from php file, you can take any name as "param".

Comment: Hello again, Mihir. I've set the function irParaMinhasReservas() normally. However, the code I've set in index.php is not working. It only loads the header when i click on the link index.php?param=1. The beggining of index.php is this: <?php
 session_start("usuario");
 if(isset($_GET['param'])){
  abreAba(2, logado);
 }
?>